# espresso times out on CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(name, value)

Tags: android, android-espresso, cookiemanager

I'm writing an espresso test for a login activity that sets cookies:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(name, value)
```

But the test hangs at the above code then times out. Looking into the setCookie code I think it calls some native jni method.

I can't try setCookie(name, value, callback) because the code needs to support API level 19.

Any idea why this is happening?

Many thanks!

Update: just to add that this seems to only happen when test is run against emulator. It runs without problem against a real device.